# What is better syntax with chain if else in swift

Tags: swift, generics

I would like to write a function that execute couple of subset function based on return value of subset function. The logic is
if funcA is successfully executed return
Otherwise executes funcB
if funcB is successfully executed return
Otherwise executes funcC
I have followed snippet but wondering if any better syntax in swift?

```
func funcA() -> Bool {
    // Implementation of funcA goes here
    // Replace this with your actual logic for funcA
    return true // Replace 'true' with the actual result of funcA
}

func funcB() -> Bool {
    // Implementation of funcB goes here
    // Replace this with your actual logic for funcB
    return false // Replace 'false' with the actual result of funcB
}

func funcC() {
    // Implementation of funcC goes here
    // Replace this with your actual logic for funcC
    print("Function C executed")
}

func performLogic() {
    let resultA = funcA()
    
    if resultA {
        return // Return early if resultA is true
    }
    
    let resultB = funcB()
    
    if !resultB {
        funcC()
    }
}

performLogic()
```

Comment: With this code there is no other syntax.

Comment: Except `guard/else` (which are used for "early return" on conditions), I don't think there is more to do.

Comment: Any better flow for the same logic?

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, your current code is very readable and I don't think it needs a "better" syntax. You can make the syntax shorter, but that would make it less readable.

For example, you can do (assuming you don't need the intermediate results):

```
if !funcA() && !funcB() {
    funcC()
}
```

This takes advantage of the fact that `&&` is lazy.

If you can change the return types of the functions, then changing `funcC` to also return a `Bool` allows you to do:

```
funcA() || funcB() || funcC()
```

Alternatively, change them all to return a `Void?`. Return `nil` when it is not successful, and return `()` otherwise. This allows you to use the `??` operator, which is a common idiom to provide a "default" when something fails

```
funcA() ?? funcB() ?? funcC()
```

That said, returning `Void?` looks quite weird. If the functions actually return some meaningful value, then I would recommend doing it this way.

Comment: You have nicely demonstrated, that the OP's original code is quite readable. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use locally scoped variables only when really needed. This approach reduces complexity and can make the code cleaner. If the functions are named meaningfully, using locally scoped variables might not be necessary at all.

Implementing early returns in Swift, typically a `guard` is used.

```
func performLogic() {
    guard !funcA() else { return }
    guard funcB() else { return }

    funcC()
}
```

Comment: I have more statement to execute after funcC. i cannot use guard to early return performLogic()

Comment: That use case is not mentioned/described in your question, however providing all relevant details when asking a question is crucial for getting accurate and helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use [guard_1](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/100137) or [guard_2](https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/guard-statements/)

```
func funcA() -> Bool {
    // Implementation of funcA goes here
    // Replace this with your actual logic for funcA
    return true // Replace 'true' with the actual result of funcA
}

func funcB() -> Bool {
    // Implementation of funcB goes here
    // Replace this with your actual logic for funcB
    return false // Replace 'false' with the actual result of funcB
}

func funcC() {
    // Implementation of funcC goes here
    // Replace this with your actual logic for funcC
    print("Function C executed")
}

func performLogic() {
    guard funcA() else {
        return // Return early if resultA is true
    }
    
    guard !funcB() else {
        funcC()
        return
    }
}

performLogic()
```

Comment: I have one stamen need to execute. i cannot use guard to early return performLogic()